# JTable will set to editable after converting ResultSet to TableModel with DbUtils. How to make it non-editable again?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Here is My Code for doing this`

```
public static void addSong(String[] fileDetail, JTable SongData_Table)
{
    try {
        con = DBConnection.getCon();
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into songs values (null,'" + fileDetail[0] + "', '" + fileDetail[1] + "',null,null)");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from songs");

        TableModel model = DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs);
        SongData_Table.setModel(model);

        if (con != null) {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in Stmt " + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. `SongData_Table` should be `songDataTable`.

Override the `isCellEditable(...)` method of the JTable, instead of the TableModel.

```
JTable songDataTable = new JTable()
{
    @Override boolean isCellEditatable(int row, int column)
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In [`DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel`](http://technojeeves.com/index.php/9-freebies/22-resultset-to-tablemodel), replace

```
return new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames);
```

and return a `TableModel` that overrides `isCellEditable()`:

```
return new DefaultTableModel(rows, columnNames){

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the method isCellEditable:

```
 //instance table model
  DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {

  @Override
  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
   //all cells false
   return false;
   }
 };

  table.setModel(tableModel);
```

or....

```
  table.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: DefaultTableModel doesn't work with DbUtils and I can't use table.setEnabled(false) as after that i can't use click event on table.

Comment: Don't use `setEnabled`, this will disable ALL interactions, including row selection...not a good idea...

Comment: @AnandChokshi Then don't use `DbUtils`, because the `isCellEditable` method is the correct method to use..

Answer (score 0):

using  Vector Convert ResultSet to TableModel instead:

```
.......    
Vector column = new Vector();
column.addElement("Columnname1");
column.addElement("Columnname2");
column.addElement("Columnname3");
........
//data Vector
Vector data = new Vector();
while (rs.next()) {
Vector temp = new Vector();
temp.addElement(rs.getString(1));
temp.addElement(rs.getString(2));
 temp.addElement(rs.getString(3));
  ........      
data.addElement(temp);
}
//append to JTable
yourtable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(data,column){

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
   return false;
}
});
......
```